# Translate Linear gradient using Webkit gradient

Tags: css

I am try to get the equivalent of:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgb(166, 230, 230), rgb(231, 231, 231) 5%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 15%);
```

using webkit gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left` instead of `90deg` for `-webkit`.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wyv4f/1/